# Pandas dataframe filiter out groups of small sizes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to filter out groups of small sizes and the filter function throws  ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed. I caan't post my code it's too specific and I can't reproduce the issue with just random set of data. Have anybody come across this? I've seen the other post for the same error but it wasn't too helpful

As a work-around I'm trying to do the same thing filter does with groupby and apply but it doesn't work as expected. Any suggestions?

```
       dff = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.arange(8), 'B': list('aabbbbcc')})
       dff['C'] = np.arange(8)

       def f(x):
         if len(x)>2: 
           return x
         else:
          return None
       dff.groupby('B').apply(f)

       B
        a         A    B    C
        2  NaN  NaN  NaN
        3  NaN  NaN ...
        b       A  B  C
        2  2  b  2
        3  3  b  3
        4  4  b  4
        5 ...
        c         A    B    C
        2  NaN  NaN  NaN
        3  NaN  NaN ...
       dtype: object
```

Comment: Wouldn't a simple `dff.where(dff > 2)` suffice for such a case?

Comment: @Nanashi : No. That will return the dataframe values where the values are >2. OP wants to groupby a column and return a dataframe with only those groups that have more than two rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your example code is that the `apply` doesn't know what to do with the `None` when putting the dataframe back together. Your `apply` function needs to output the same type of object every time. If you return `pd.DataFrame()` instead of None you should get what you're looking for.

Comment: That's it! Thanks!
`   def f(x):
     if len(x)>2: return x
     else: return pd.DataFrame(columns=x.columns)
   dff.groupby('B',group_keys=False).apply(f)
`